# Need help making a Windows bootable USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

I bought a laptop that came with Windows 8 on it.  Used another laptop running Linux mint and the dd command to make a ubuntu bootable USB and thats what I'm running now.  I want to create a Windows 10 bootable USB on my Ubuntu machine but I'll be damned if I can get this thing working.  I downloaded a fresh .iso from microsoft (and tried three others I had on hand, including a Windows 7 .iso) and used the following procedure:

Created partition table on the USB drive (Tried msdos and gpt) and formatted a new partition (Tried NTFS and FAT32).

Flagged partition as bootable within gparted.

Unmounted the partition with:

sudo umount /dev/sdb1

Copied Win10 image over to the drive with:

sudo dd if=Win10.iso of=/dev/sdb && sync

Now when I reboot and try to boot to the USB I get no error messages it just boots right into my Ubuntu installation on my hard drive.

Funny thing is if I plug in my Ubuntu bootable USB it works just fine.  Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'Swiss Army Knife' `gnome-disk-utility` to create the Windows installation media. Open `Disks` from the dash and select Restore Disk Image from the menu on the top right of the application. Choose the Windows installation file and the USB drive to write it to. Click Start Restoring, now you should be able to boot from the Windows USB media properly.